# MVC custom errors not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have set up the /shared/error.cshtml page in my views to show a more friendly error message. however it is not showing when the user hits an error.

My web.config file has:

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="On" />
```

and my global.asax.cs has:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute ());
    }
```

yet the error message i get is still the basic

```
`Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on the local server machine, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable the details to be viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to "Off".`
```

What am i missing?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? There is no point in having CustomErrors set to On if you don't specify a custom error page, right? Basically it says that an error occurred and there was an error showing the custom error page ...

Comment: I want it to go to the error.cshtml specified in the shared layout. it does this by default when you create a MVC application, but we built ours from scratch so i dont know how to

Comment: You should have an ErrorController with an action that displays this view. And the action should have the following annotations: [HandleError(View = "Error", ExceptionType = typeof(Exception))]

Comment: You should have an ErrorController with an action that displays this view. And the action should have the following annotations:

Answer (score 0):

**activate custom errors in the Web.config by adding the following lines under**

```
<system.web>:

<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error">
  <error redirect="/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404"/>
  <error redirect="/Error/InternalServerError" statusCode="500"/>
</customErrors>
```

Note: You can set mode=”Off” to disable custom errors which could be helpful while developing or debugging. Setting mode=”RemoteOnly” activates custom errors only for remote clients,

Comment: That would be if I were pointing my error to a controller or any custom views, which i'm not. i'm trying to use the default functionality. also, even when i do add that. It doesnt work.

With all due respect, word for wording another answer on SA doesnt help me, especially when they are doing something more customised

Answer (score 0):

You should have an ErrorController with an action that displays your error view. And the action should have the following annotations:

```
[HandleError(View = "Error", ExceptionType = typeof(Exception))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, some dynamic content was not being loaded when there was an error as it was not using the base controller, therefore the error handling was throwing an error